# Java Hot Code Replace (HCR) not updating in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, eclipse-jdt, vscode-debugger

It used to be working, I thought was because of the vscode 1.47.1, upgraded to 1.47.2 or downgrade to 1.46.1, same thing.  Java extension and java debug extension are both at the latest version.

The HCR is set to auto.
Auto build is enabled.

Tried HCR to manual, always get:

> Cannot find any changed classes for hot replace!

Any suggestions why this has stopped working?  I was using jdk 1.8, also tried java 11, same problem.

Also wanted to mention, if I change the signature of a private method, it doesn't give me any warning.  It used to tell me that failed to do the code replace, and ask me I want to restart the project.

thanks!

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Were you able to solve yours?